# Robolectric 2.0 & RoboGuice 2.0 Integration

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, robolectric, roboguice

I'm searching the Web and still, not found nothing on how to integrate Robolectric 2.0 with RoboGuice 2.0, I also use Mockito as Mocking Framework, and there's no problem with it. Just don't know how to integrate Robolectric with RoboGuice.

Is there any guide or way to integrate them? Robolectric 2.0 lacks of documentation

Thank you very much.

Comment: But what is wrong with Robolectric 2.x and RoboGuice?

Comment: Don't know how to integrate them for Unit Testing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you checked `Astroboy` example?

You can find code with `Robolectric` tests here - https://github.com/roboguice/roboguice/tree/master/astroboy

Comment: I'm reviewing It, I'll give it a try! Thank you!